# scipy curve_fit with integer parameters

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to use scipy's curve_fit to compute the offset in x and y between two grayscale images as 2-D numpy ndarrays. However, this requires that the parameters of the function that I feed curve_fit needs integer arguments.

So I have a function that takes three arguments: a flattened array, and offsets along two axes. It accomplishes the offset correctly and returns a re-flattened array for all integer offsets, but curve_fit always returns p0.

Is it possible to make curve_fit work with integer parameters?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach here probably is to define a function of two floating point offsets which performs interpolation between integer points:

```
def func_orig(xint,yint):
    ....

def func_new(x,y):
    x1 = int(x)
    y1 = int(y)
    x2 = x1 + 1
    y2 = y1 + 1
    val = func_orig(x1,y1) * (x2-x)*(y2-y)+
          func_orig(x1,y2) * (x2-x)*(y1-y)+
          func_orig(x2,y1) * (x1-x)*(y2-y)+
          func_orig(x2,y2) * (x1-x)*(y1-y)
    val = val / (x2-x1)/(y2-y1)
    return val
```

Comment: I may try this, but I think it may be a bit slow on 1048x1048 images.

Do you think this would be a good use of scipy's interpolation methods?